# How to go about creating a Jframe that holds three regions

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

"Create an educational program for children that distinguishes between vowels and consonants as the user clicks buttons. Create 26 JButtons, each labeled with a different letter of the alphabet. Create a JFrame to hold three JPanels in a two by-two grid. Randomly select eight of the 26 JButtons and place four in each of the first two JPanels. Add a JLabel to the third JPanel. When the user clicks
a JButton, the text of the JLabel identifies the button’s letter as a vowel or
consonant, and then a new randomly selected letter replaces the letter on the
JButton."

So, I'm wondering if someone can point me in the right direction with going about this. No, it's not homework, I am just going through my java textbook and would greatly appreciate any pointers or sense of direction on how to go about writing this.

Thanks!

Comment: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) would be my first port of call

Comment: Also the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) deserves a read.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are wanting to do: https://github.com/briancha/Java-2-assignments/blob/master/JVowelConsonant.java